# Application of Residue Theorem and limits

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, summation, residue-calculus

I am trying the following problem from Fisher's Complex Variables book:

If $f$ is analytic on a plane except at poles $\gamma_1, \cdots \gamma_N$ and none of them are integers and $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} |z(f(z)|= 0$. Show that $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(n)= -\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\operatorname{Res} (fC; \gamma_j)$ and $C(z)=\pi \cot(\pi z)$

Based on the hint provided I was able to prove that the residue was $f$.
 However I am not sure how to attempt this problem further.

Comment: $C(z)$ quite certainly is *not* bounded. $\cot z = \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}$, and $\cot(\pi z)$ thus has poles at the integers (because then $\sin (\pi z) = 0$).

Comment: @fgp: Ahh you are correct! That was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^2-n^2}$.

Also, notice that $|zf(z)|\rightarrow 0$ gives you nice convergence for $\oint_R f(z)C(z)dz$ when you take $R\rightarrow\infty$, where the contour integral is on a disk of radius $R$ about the origin.

Comment: I am not sure how to use your hint. But till now I have managed to find that the poles of $\pi cot(\pi z)$ are integers with order 1. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Try to write down the exact definition of the residue of $fC$. What do you get?

Comment: I have computed the residue and its just $f$. Is that correct?